# SQL Group by joining with time difference

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-science

I have this college project with a good focus on the frontend, but I'm struggling with a SQL query (PostgreSQL) that needs to be executed at one of the backend endpoints.

The table I'm speaking of is the following:

| id | todo_id | column_id | time_in_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 259190 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 259190 | 10300 | 30 |
| 2 | 259190 | 10001 | 60 |
| 3 | 259190 | 10600 | 90 |
| 4 | 259190 | 6 | 30 |

A good way to simplify what it is, is saying it's a to-do organizer by vertical columns where each column would be represented by its `column_id`, and each row is task column change event.

With all that said what I need to get the job done is to generate a view (or another suggested better way) from this table that will show how long each task spent on each `column_id`. Also for a certain `todo_id`, `column_id` is not unique, so that could be multiple events on column 10300 and the table below would group by it and sum them

For example, the table above would output a view like this:

| id | todo_id | time_in_column_3 | time_in_column_10300 | time_in_column_10001 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 259190 | 0 | 30 | 60 | ... |

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from   crosstab(
               'select todo_id, id, time_in_status
                from t'
               )
as t(todo_id int, "time_in_column_3" int, "time_in_column_10300" int, "time_in_column_10001" int, "time_in_column_10600" int, "time_in_column_6" int )
```

| todo_id | time_in_column_3 | time_in_column_10300 | time_in_column_10001 | time_in_column_10600 | time_in_column_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 259190 | 0 | 30 | 60 | 90 | 30 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sfXI7B13?hide=4)